# How to decode a unicode-like string in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have unicode-like strings but with slash escaped. For example, `'\\u000D'`. I need to decode them as normal strings. The above example should be convert to `'\r'` which `'\u000D'` corresponds to.

Answer (score 11):

Use the `unicode-escape` codec.

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.decode('\\u000D', 'unicode-escape')
'\r'
```

Comment: the same result without `codecs` - `'\\u000D'.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape')` or with other encoding `'\\u000D'.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode-escape')`